# JavaScript interactive chat animation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, chat

Let me preface this by saying that while I do have experience with HTML and CSS, I'm still trying to grasp the basics of JavaScript.

A friend and I are trying to use the skeleton of this chat code from codepen: http://codepen.io/clintioo/pen/HAkjq

JavaScript function:

```
    function handleMessage(event) {

                  var chatNewThread = document.createElement('li'),
                    chatNewMessage = document.createTextNode(event.data);

                  // Add message to chat thread and scroll to bottom
                  chatNewThread.appendChild(chatNewMessage);
                  chatThread.appendChild(chatNewThread);
                  chatThread.scrollTop = chatThread.scrollHeight;

                  // Clear text value
                  chatWindowMessage.value = '';
                }
```

HTML:

```
            <ul class="chat-thread">
                      <li>Message 1</li>
                      <li>Message 2</li>
                      <li>Message 3</li>
            </ul>

                <form class="chat-window">
                  <input id="userInput" class="chat-window-message" name="chat-window-message" type="text" autofocus />
                </form>

        </section>
        </div>
```

We find that once we start editing the code offline, the input doesn't work like it should. We've even tried copying it exactly, but the text that goes into the input form doesn't get added to the animation.

I'm fairly certain that whatever the problem is comes from the function above, but my limited knowledge of JavaScript is keeping me stumped.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a good chance that it is because it requires jquery - try adding this to the head section of your html file and run it again ```<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>```

Comment: I don't think jQuery is required. Have you checked the console for errors? Try putting your code into a codepen or jsfiddle and then link it in your question.

Comment: Alright, thank you both. I had errors both with how I was referencing the scripting as well as general formatting inside the tags.